# How to make force-click in finder show info on item?

Tags: macbook-pro, finder, macos, trackpad

How can I change the action of the force click in finder from preview (which I find useless most of the time) to Get Info (which I use very frequently)?

Comment: You could try bettertouchtool to change that, but by default the action cannot be changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [BetterTouchTool](https://www.boastr.net) to map a <del>2</del> 1 finger Force Click to open Get Info. <del>It's not possible to remap a [single finger Force Click with BetterTouchTool](https://github.com/fifafu/BetterTouchTool/issues/88).</del> With **BetterTouchTool 2.317c**, it is now possible to remap a single finger Force Click.

1. Add Finder as an application so the gesture only takes effect in Finder.
2. Under Trackpads, add a new gesture of ‘<del>2</del> 1 Finger Force Click’ and choose the predefined action ‘Left Click’.
3. Choose ‘Attach Additional Action’ and enter the custom keyboard shortcut ⌘I.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a source for "It's not possible to remap a single finger Force Click"?

Comment: @the I've added a link, in this case the automatic left click wouldn't be a problem as the first action is a left click anyway, but so far that gesture hasn't been made available in the app.

Comment: @the Remapping single finger Force Click has now been added to the app today!